# When can conservation of energy be used to find the average force on an object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation

I have tried the following question from  the [2020 ENGAA section 1 paper](https://www.physicsandmathstutor.com/pdf-pages/?pdf=https%3A%2F%2Fpmt.physicsandmathstutor.com%2Fdownload%2FAdmissions%2FENGAA%2FPapers%2FENGAA%25202020%2520Section%25201.pdf) in two different ways, but I get different answers:

[image]

(Question 11)

The correct answer is easy to get using Newton's Second Law: The final velocity is equal to the gradient after 5s (6ms-1), then the average force is given by the average rate of change of momentum F = (6 * 800)/5 = 960N

However, using the work-energy principle I no longer get the correct answer: Fs = 1/2mv^2 so F = (mv^2)/(2s) = (800 * 36)/(2 * 10) = 1440N

Therefore, my question is why does the second method fail? All I can think of is that the first method gives the time averaged force, but the second method gives the distance averaged force, this comes from the fact that work is the integral of force with respect to distance and impulse is the integral of force with respect to time.

If this is correct, how would you properly justify it and when would time averaged force be equal to distance averaged force?

Comment: I'm breaking my head here. Something's fishy. F=960N -> a=1.2 -> x=15 != 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated, the first method yields time-averaged force whereas the second answer yields distance-averaged force, which are in general different. Mathematically, the time averaged force $F_t$ is given by

$F_{t} = \frac{1}{T} \int F dt$

and the distance (technically displacement) averaged force $F_s$ is given by

$F_s = \frac{1}{S} \int F ds = \frac{1}{S} \int F \frac{ds}{dt} dt$

which is not in general equal to $F_t$.

Now note that one way for $F_t$ to equal $F_s$ is if the car were travelling a constant velocity $v$:

$F_s = \frac{1}{S} \int F v dt = \frac{v}{S} \int F dt = \frac{1}{T} \int F dt = F_t$